# C: How to optimize memory usage with mergesort on 20million records

Tags: c, mergesort

So I have big file that I have to sort with merge sort.

File dimension: 700MB with 20 million records.

Now my program is taking like 7BG of ram and I guess that's bad.
I think I did some useless allocation but I'm not sure of it, any help is appreciated.

let's start:

```
typedef struct {
    void **array; // array of struct type record
    long used;
    long size;
    int (*precedes)(void *, void *); // function for comparison 
} Array;
```

---

some functions to use with `struct Array`:

```
void initArray(Array *a, int (*precedes)(void*, void*)) {
    if (precedes == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_create: precedes parameter cannot be NULL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    a->array = (void**)malloc(INITIAL_SIZE * sizeof(void*));
    if (a->array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_locate: unable to allocate memory for the a-> array");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = INITIAL_SIZE;
    a->precedes = precedes;
}

void insertArray(Array *a, void *element) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_element: array parameter cannot be NULL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (element == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_element: element parameter cannot be NULL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = (void**)realloc(a->array,(unsigned long)a->size * sizeof(void *));
        if (a->array == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"array_resize: unable to reallocate memory to host the new element");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void *get_element(Array *a, long index) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array parameter cannot be NULL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (index >= a->size) {
        fprintf(stderr,  "Index %lu is out of the array bounds", index);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return a->array[index];
}

unsigned long array_size(Array *a) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_size: ordered_array parameter cannot be NULL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return a->used;
}

int array_is_empty(Array *a) {
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "array_is_empty: ordered_array parameter cannot be NULL");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return a->used == 0;
}

void freeArray(Array *a) {
    free(a->array);
    a->array = NULL;
    a->used = a->size = 0;
    free(a);
}
```

---

Merge sort, I guess the problem is with `void ** temp = malloc(sizeof(void*) * a->used);`:

```
void mergeSort(Array *a, long lb, long ub) {
    if (lb < ub) {
        long mid = (lb + ub) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, lb, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, ub);
        merge(a, lb, mid, ub);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

void merge(Array *a, long lb, long mid, long ub) {
    long i = lb;
    long j = mid + 1;
    long k = lb;
    void **temp = malloc(sizeof(void*) * a->used); // this is bad I guess
    while (i <= mid && j <= ub) {
        if (a->precedes(a->array[i], a->array[j]) < 0 || a->precedes(a->array[i], a->array[j]) == 0) {
            temp[k] = a->array[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            temp[k] = a->array[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    if (i > mid) {
        while (j <= ub) {
            temp[k] = a->array[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    } else {
        while (i <= mid) {
            temp[k] = a->array[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (i = lb ; i <= ub; i++) {
        a->array[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

---

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lib.h"
#include <time.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1024

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *s_data;
    int i_data;
    double d_data;
} Record_t;

//function to get csv file fields
char *getfield(char *line, int num, char *parser) {
    char *tok = strtok(line, parser);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        tok = strtok(NULL, parser);
    }
    if (tok != NULL) {
        return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}

//function for comparison two strings
static int precedes_record_string_field(void *r1_p, void *r2_p) {
    if (r1_p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "precedes_string: the first parameter is a null pointer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (r2_p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "precedes_string: the second parameter is a null pointer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Record_t *rec1_p = (Record_t *)r1_p;
    Record_t *rec2_p = (Record_t *)r2_p;
    return strcmp(rec1_p->s_data, rec2_p->s_data);
}

//loading the file
void load_file(Array *a, FILE *f, char *parser) {
    printf("Loading file\n");
    char line[BUFFSIZE];
    while (fgets(line, BUFFSIZE, f)) {
        char *tmp = strdup(line);
        Record_t *record = malloc(sizeof(Record_t));
        record->id = atoi(getfield(tmp, 0, parser));
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
        tmp = strdup(line);
        record->s_data = malloc(sizeof(char) * 150);
        strcpy(record->s_data, getfield(tmp, 1, parser));
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
        tmp = strdup(line);
        record->i_data = atoi(getfield(tmp, 2, parser));
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
        tmp = strdup(line);
        record->d_data = atof(getfield(tmp, 3, parser));
        insertArray(a, record);
        free(tmp);
    }
    printf("File loaded\n");
}

// writing the file
void writeToFile(Array *a, char *name) {
    FILE *fptr = fopen(name, "w");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a->used; i++) {
        Record_t *rec1_p = (Record_t *)a->array[i];
        fprintf(fptr, "%d,%s,%d,%lf\n", rec1_p->id, rec1_p->s_data, rec1_p->i_data, rec1_p->d_data);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}

//main
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Array *a = (Array *)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Missing input file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    int k = atoi(argv[2]);
    initArray(a, precedes_record_string_field);
    load_file(a, f, ",");
    mergeSort(a, 0, a->used - 1);
    writeToFile(a, "../recors_string.csv");
    printf("done\n");

    free(f);
    freeArray(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks you in advance for your help.Appreciate any help.

---

**Update**:

I wanted to this in the merge before the last for function :

```
free(a->array);
a->array = NULL;
for (i = lb; i <= ub; i++) {
    a->array[i] = temp[i];
}
```

but doing in this way it gives me segmentation fault. For what I know after the free you can use the variable.

Comment: Your `merge()` function allocates memory, possibly a lot of it, but it does not appear to free that memory when done with it.  This constitutes a serious memory leak.

Comment: Your internal representation of the data is inefficient.  It would be more space efficient to allocate one block of memory for *all* the records, instead of allocating a separate block per record.  The block-per record requires an additional pointer to be maintained for each record (more than 20% overhead) and it probably is wasteful on account of the granularity of of allocated blocks, too (possibly another 50% or more overhead).  The array of pointers layout allows for computationally more efficient swaps, however, so this is in part a space *vs*. speed tradeoff.

Comment: There is also up to another 100% space overhead from your approach to dynamically growing the allocation for the array.  You could do much better on size here, without too much cost to computational efficiency, by making a good initial estimate of the number of records, and increasing that by fixed size chunks if it happens to not be large enough.  The quality of the initial estimate is the key to computational efficiency here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks john ill try to modify my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your memory allocation strategies:

- the `merge` function allocates a temporary array `temp` with far too many entries and never frees it. This is a strong candidate for running out of memory and since you do not check for malloc failure, undefined behavior will occur when `malloc` returns `NULL`.
- `getfield` does not test for `strtok` failure, causing undefined behavior on invalid input.
- `loadfile` allocates and frees many temporary arrays. Using a local array would avoid fragmentation during this phase.

Some other issues:

- it is better to use type `size_t` for counts of elements instead of `long`.
- you should write `fclose(f)` instead of `free(f)`.
- the test `if (index >= a->size)` in `get_element` should be `if (index >= a->used)`. As coded, you might return an uninitialized element.
- `insertArray` is a misnomer: you should use `appendArray` or `array_append` for consistency.

Here is a modified version of the mergesort functions:

```
void mergeSort(Array *a, size_t lb, size_t ub) {
    if (lb < ub) {
        size_t mid = lb + (ub - lb) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, lb, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, ub);
        merge(a, lb, mid, ub);
    }
}

void merge(Array *a, size_t lb, size_t mid, size_t ub) {
    size_t i = lb;
    size_t j = mid + 1;
    size_t k = 0;
    void **temp = malloc(sizeof(void*) * (ub + 1 - lb);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory in merge\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* select elements from either half according to the comparison function */
    while (i <= mid && j <= ub) {
        if (a->precedes(a->array[i], a->array[j]) <= 0) {
            temp[k++] = a->array[i++];
        } else {
            temp[k++] = a->array[j++];
        }
    }
    /* copy the remaining elements from the left half */
    while (i <= mid) {
        temp[k++] = a->array[i++];
    }
    /* no need to copy the remaining elements from the right half:
       they are already in place */

    /* copy the sorted slice back to the array */
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        a->array[lb + i] = temp[i];
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

Here is a modified version of the program, using less memory:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "lib.h"

#define BUFFSIZE 1024

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int i_data;   // group int fields together for better structure packing
    char *s_data;
    double d_data;
} Record_t;

// function to get csv file fields
// use strspn and strcspn to avoid modifying the line
// return a pointer to the beginning of the field
char *getfield(const char *line, int num, const char *delimiters) {
    const char *p = line;   // points to the beginning of the field
    while (num --> 0) {
        p += strcspn(p, delimiters); // skip contents
        p += strspn(p, delimiters); // skip delimiters
    }
    return (char *)p;
}

//loading the file
void load_file(Array *a, FILE *f, const char *delimiters) {
    printf("Loading file\n");
    char line[BUFFSIZE];
    while (fgets(line, BUFFSIZE, f)) {
        Record_t *record = malloc(sizeof(Record_t));
        if (record == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory for record: %s\n", line);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        record->id = atoi(getfield(line, 0, delimiters));
        char *p = getfield(tmp, 1, parser);
        record->s_data = strndup(p, strcspn(p, delimiters));
        record->i_data = atoi(getfield(tmp, 2, delimiters));
        record->d_data = atof(getfield(tmp, 3, delimiters));
        insertArray(a, record);
    }
    printf("File loaded\n");
}

// writing the file
int writeToFile(Array *a, const char *name) {
    FILE *fptr = fopen(name, "w");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s: %s", name, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    for (long i = 0; i < a->used; i++) {
        Record_t *rec1_p = (Record_t *)a->array[i];
        fprintf(fptr, "%d,%s,%d,%lf\n", rec1_p->id, rec1_p->s_data, rec1_p->i_data, rec1_p->d_data);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Array *a = (Array *)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory for Array\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Missing input file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    initArray(a, precedes_record_string_field);
    load_file(a, f, ",\n");
    mergeSort(a, 0, a->used - 1);
    writeToFile(a, "../recors_string.csv");
    printf("done\n");

    fclose(f);
    freeArray(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a one time allocation of a second 700 mb array to use with the merge sort and use indexing to select sub-arrays from the original and second arrays. Total memory will be 1.4 gb plus local variables, which shouldn't be an issue with a 64 bit OS.

Comment: thanks for the answer , can you give me an example of how can i use indexing ?

Comment: with this dropped to 4gb of ram usage-

Comment: @Singh - take a look at the [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) .